# UIActivityViewController display email modal view controller over the navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have an application with navigation bar and a view controller that displays UIActivityViewController when a button is pressed.
Problem is that when mail is chosen the mail modal view controller covers the navigation bar (image attached - notice the cancel button on the top left).
Any ideas?

Here is the code for displaying the activity view controller-

```
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
                                                        initWithActivityItems:@[message, self.currentImage] applicationActivities:nil];
    [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSString *flurryEvent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Shared chapter %@", self.chapterIndex];
            [Flurry logEvent:flurryEvent];
        });
    }];
```

BTW- same problem with messages but i guess if I solve one the other will be solved too.
[image]

Comment: so what you want from that

Comment: I want to be able to either remove the image from the navigation bar or make mail modal view a bit shorter when mail modal view controller is displayed.

Comment: remove the image from the tab bar ? means. in your question you haven't mention the tab bar words any where

Comment: Sorry just edited comment. I meant navigation bar.

Comment: when you call mail composer set your self.navigationBar image as nil or change what ever you want try this

Comment: Problem is I am not calling mail composer, the UIActivityViewController is calling it.

Comment: ok where you call through set navigation bar image as nil

Comment: That's the problem. I can't find an appropriate event to hide the image in. I will edit question to add code. UIActivityViewController only has a completion handler and MFMailComposerDelegate only responds to finishWithResults.

Comment: I can see 2 options : option 1) when you will present the UIActivityViewController (I know it's probably not nice to see). option 2) you have to create your own UIActivities (mail...) (where you'll be able to know if selected => remove image from navBar) : I've saw this, may be it can help http://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/steven-beyers/cocoaconf-dc-recap-sharing-uiactivityviewcontroller

Comment: if possible link your project

Comment: Just tried option 1.  Some how the mail composer brings the image back!
Option 2 seems like a over kill for just this problem.
 I do not want to share a link to my project here. Can you private message me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed!

```
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
                                                    initWithActivityItems:@[message, self.currentImage] applicationActivities:nil];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:nil] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
activityViewController.completionHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
};
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    });
}];
```